# Existence and uniqueness of solution for the same problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, optimization

In a programming course, students are tasked with writing a code to find $n$  points that satisfy the following conditions:

- $0=x_0<x_1<...<x_n=1$
- $\displaystyle {\sum_{1\leq j\leq n}}_{j\neq i} \frac {1}{(x_i-x_j)|x_i-x_j|}=0, \forall i=2,...n-1$

Here is the provided code (The purpose of my question is not to discuss the code, but the question is towards the end of my post. If anyone is interested, they can test the code on an [online compiler](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/))

```
   import numpy as np

def objective_function(x):
    n = len(x)
    result = 0
    for i in range(1, n - 1):
        sum_left = sum(1 / (x[i] - x[k])**2 for k in range(i) if x[i] != x[k])
        sum_right = sum(1 / (x[i] - x[k])**2 for k in range(i+1, n) if x[i] != x[k])
        result += (sum_left - sum_right)**2

    return result

def random_search(n, num_iterations):
    best_solution = None
    best_objective = float('inf')

    for _ in range(num_iterations):
        current_solution = np.sort(np.random.rand(n-2))
        current_objective = objective_function(np.concatenate(([0], current_solution, [1])))

        if current_objective < best_objective:
            best_objective = current_objective
            best_solution = current_solution

    return np.concatenate(([0], best_solution, [1]))

# Get the value of n from the user
n = int(input("Enter the value of n (greater than 2): "))

# Number of random search iterations
num_iterations = 10000

# Random Search
optimal_values = random_search(n, num_iterations)

# Display the optimal values for x_i, x_0, and x_n
print("\nOptimal values for x_i with n =", n, ":", optimal_values)
```

I have tested the code for a few values of n, and it seems to me that theoretically these points exist and are unique for any fixed n. **I have no idea how to demonstrate their existence or uniqueness**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: let $$f(x_1,  \ldots, x_{n-1}) = \sum_{0\le i< j\le n} \frac1{x_j - x_i}$$

defined on $\Omega:=\left\{(x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1}): 0=x_0 < x_1 < \cdots < x_{n-1} < x_n =1\right\}$.

Can you prove that $f$ is convex? What is the limit of $f$ on the boundary of $\Omega$? Is $\Omega$ open? What is the gradient of $f$?

Comment: Thank you, I will reflect on your questions

Comment: Ok thank you, perfect